# Program for password validation

Tags: java

I want to write a program that checks the inserted password for:

- Length is minimum of 8
- At least 1 uppercase letter
- At least 1 lowercase letter
- At least 3 digits

I wrote this program, but it doesn't give me the right output:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        boolean flag = validate(input);
        if (flag = true) {
            System.out.println("password verified");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not a good password");
        }
    }
    public static boolean validate(String input)  {
        boolean flag = false;

        int uppercaseCounter = 0;
        int lowercaseCounter = 0;
        int digitCounter = 0;
        int letterCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<(input.length()); i++) {
            int totalCounter = digitCounter + letterCounter;
            if (totalCounter >= 8 && digitCounter >= 3 && uppercaseCounter > 0 && lowercaseCounter > 0) {
                flag = true;
            }
            else {
                if (Character.isDigit(i)) {
                    digitCounter++;
                }
                if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
                    letterCounter++;
                }
                if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                    uppercaseCounter++;
                }
                if (Character.isLowerCase(i)) {
                    lowercaseCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: `if (flag == true)` notice it should be  double `==`!

Comment: @TDG Or, better yet, simply `if (flag)`.

Comment: what is the input and output then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the catch:

```
if (flag = true)
{
    System.out.println("password verified");
}
```

`=` is an *assignment operator* `==` is the relational operator. To fix, do `flag==true`.

Also, in your method, you are comparing `i`, which is the counter, and not the 
`char` At  `i`. So do this

```
if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))){ //Do this for all Character.isSomething() Methods
```

for all the *checks* you make.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually checking the `i` counter in your various if instead of the input string...

use something like

```
char c = s.charAt(i);
```

and check the input chars

moreover you should change the check `if(flag = true)` with `if(flag)`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (flag = true)
{
    System.out.println("password verified");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("not a good password");
}
```

to

```
if (flag)
{
    System.out.println("password verified");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("not a good password");
}
```

When you write `if(flag=true)` then you are doing an assignment operation and not an equality comparison.

Also, the logic should be `Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))` since you want to check the character at `i` and not `i` itself.

To conclude, I would like to say that this problem would be fun to solve with `Regular Expressions`. Check [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex) tutorial on regular expressions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, this code should be moved below the counter increments:

```
int totalCounter = digitCounter + letterCounter;
if (totalCounter >= 8 && digitCounter >= 3 && uppercaseCounter > 0 && lowercaseCounter > 0) {
    flag = true;
}
```

Otherwise, you run the risk of returning false when your password would become valid on the last character.